# placing zoomed in videos in html

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a very simple html page in which I want to place 4 videos one under the other.

There are various ways to do this, using table, using div. And they are all fine with me.

However I want to use "transform" to scale the videos (that are simple iphone videos and they are too small for my purposes).

And when I try to do that the videos end up overlapping, because I use transform.

how do I properly do that? I have tried many (confusing - I am not an expert) options, but all of them don't work.

I got to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<style type="text/css">

video.scale2{
  transform:scale(1.5);
}


video{
width:auto;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
}


</style>
<body> 
<div >
<video  controls class="scale2">
<source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
<div>

<video  controls class="scale2">
<source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>

<p>
Video courtesy of 
<a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.
</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

you can copy this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) to see how it looks.

how do i successfully create two videos one on top of each other that are not overlapping?

Comment: try video.scale2
        {
  transform:scale(1);
        }

Comment: transform:scale(1); means that i don't scale the video. I want to enlarge it. I want to keep 1.5